# Export multiple artboards from Illustrator as separate PDFs with specific preset

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf

I searched for this over the internet but I did not find a working solution. I understand that it can't be done in Illustrator, but there is a need for a script. Can someone help me on this? There is pretty much artboards to export and there is a need to make separate files, that would be very helpful not to do it manually.

Comment: Are all of the PDFs going to use the same preset? Why not just export the document as 1 PDF and then separate the PDFs using Acrobat or another tool? The following script may work but it was created awhile ago - [Export multiple Adobe Illustrator artboards to png, jpg, pdf](https://gist.github.com/larrybotha/5baf6a9aea8da574cbbe)

Comment: Yes, same preset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know which version of AI you are using, but it is very easy in the newest release of Illustrator CC.

Use the **Export for Screens** option

[image]

**Follow these steps:**

- Select PDF as the output format (1)
- Adjust your PDF settings, by clicking the gear icon (2)
- Name your artboards by clicking on the titles, because the artboard names will be used as the PDF file names (3)

[image]

Click on Export Artboard and voila! You artboards are all now saved as inidividual PDFs.